# How to make a FragmentActivity extends AppCompat to use Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

Because my application has a `DrawerLayout`/`NavigationView`, it uses fragments to display the good page according to the selected menu item. In other words, when I click on the home page menu item, it displays the home page fragment.

Thus, there is only one activity in my application. And several fragments. The activity, of course, `extends FragmentActivity` which inherits from `android.app.Activity` (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity).

However, I would want to add a "app bar/action bar" to my app (*i.e. :* to this activity). See https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/ and in particular https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up .

According to the last link, `Toolbar` is highly recommended to set up this app bar. To use it, the activity containing it must extend `AppCompatActivity` (according to this same documentation).

I would want to use `Toolbar` in my activity that handles fragments. I think it would be the most logical. How could I do it? As you understood, there is an inheritance problem...

Comment: Why do you want     FragmentActivity to extend    AppCompatActivity?
AppCompatActivity is already extending FragmentActivity.
Do i miss some point here?

Answer (score 0):

what about using xml? build toolbar xml and use @include and intialiez on you fragment activities to support toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

As @bkrcinar pointed out in OP's comment, `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.